# Sort a list of strings

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of strings and I want to sort by the second element of each string.

Here's my code:

```
import sys

line = ""
for n in [line for line in sys.stdin.readlines()]:
    list = []
    list = n
    print list.split()
```

output:

```
['qlwekjrwer', '0']
['sdlkfsdf', '6245']
['lkdjfs', '3985']
['sdfsdfs', '4085']
```

What I want to do is sort by the second element of each string in the list in descending order. I know you would have to use the 'list.split()[1]' somehow, but I don't know where to begin.

what I want:

```
['sdlkfsdf', '6245']
['sdfsdfs', '4085']
['lkdjfs', '3985']
['qlwekjrwer', '0']
```

would i have to implement some bubble sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function:

```
result = sorted([l.split() for l in sys.stdin.readlines()], key=lambda l: int(l[1]), reverse=True)
print(result)
```

The output:

```
[['sdlkfsdf', '6245'], ['sdfsdfs', '4085'], ['lkdjfs', '3985'], ['qlwekjrwer', '0']]
```

Comment: It's almost correct, because with my example, all the digits are the same length, but when it's not the same length it doesn't sort correctly.

Comment: Like for example: is the output of your sort ['sdfsdf', '8677'], ['werwer', '6245'], ['qwerwrg', '5866], ['oiuois', '55666'], but the output should be    ['oiuois', '55666'], ['sdfsdf', '8677'], ['werwer', '6245'], ['qwerwrg', '5866],

Comment: @ChappyKhmao, use my update, It should work

Comment: Ok thanks, makes sense now